# immutable ownership (foreign key) for django-rest-framework

Tags: django, rest, serialization, django-rest-framework

How to handle the immutable ownership, an example:

> once user **create** an object like `{headline: 'test', owner: [user_id], body: 'test'}`, but after that, only body field is mutable on `__update__`.

Bellows are some solution, I am not sure which will be better:

1. Using different serializers on **create** and **update** in `view_set`
2. Using different serializers on `get_serlializer_class`, depending on `request.method`
3. Handle it with permissions, like `IsOwnerOrReadOnly`, but no field `permission`

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

`get_serializer` seems like a perfect place, you have access to request and serializer:

```
class MyAwesomeViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    # my attributes

    def get_serializer(self, instance=None, data=None,
                   files=None, many=False, partial=False):
        s = super(MyAwesomeViewSet, self).get_serializer(instance, data, files, many, partial)
        if self.request.method == 'PUT':
            s.fields['headline'].read_only = True
            s.fields['owner'].read_only = True

        return s
```

This will not give you any error if you post the read-only data, but it won't actually update the database.

Comment: This would still allow update on `PATCH`. Which points out what I find uneasy about this solution: the mapping between "HTTP method" and "updating an object" is managed elsewhere in rest-framework (and can be customized), yet here we are hardcoding it again. I think this solution might be better if it checked `instance is None` rather than the request method to determine if we are updating an existing object.

Comment: In my case, instance is None even if the request is an update of an existing object. I ended up overwriting update and setting self.is_update = True.